# How to disable @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion rule

Tags: typescript, eslint

I want to allow `data!.id`

Error:

> warning  Forbidden non-null assertion 
>   @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion

Current config:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
  ],
  plugins: ['react-hooks'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    }
  },
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions': ['warn', { assertionStyle: 'as' }],
    eqeqeq: 1,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/camelcase': 0,
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error',
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn'
  },
  globals: {
    React: 'writable'
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it work by just adding `'@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off'` to rules of the config?

Comment: Weird, I can disable any rule, but not this one.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Please add `'@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off'` to your config file like below.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  rules: {
    ...
    '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off'
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 28):

If you're attempting to disable a rule on the entire file, adding this comment in the file top to ignore will work:

```
/* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion */
```

If you're attempting to disable a rule on the next line only (rather than for an entire file), adding this comment directly above the line to ignore will work:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
```

Comment: This isn't working for me

Comment: This (the singleline ignore) DID work for me.