# Using nullable types in TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

It seems like once you define a nullable type, you have to then pepper that down the entire tree where that prop is used.  Is this the case and I just have to pepper my code which feels dirty to do this, or is there a better way to handle this with TS?

*reducers*/**company.ts**
Notice `company?` and `companies?` and featuredCompanies? below:

```
import ActionTypes from '../actions/ActionTypes';
import { Company } from '../../Interfaces';
import { CompaniesActionType, CompanyActionType } from '../actions/company/CompanyActions';

export interface CompanyState {
    company?: Company;
    companyReceived: boolean;
    companiesReceived: boolean;
    featuredCompaniesReceived?: boolean;
    companies?: Array<Company>;
    featuredCompanies?: Array<Company>;
}

const companyState: CompanyState = {
    company: undefined,
    companyReceived: false,
    companiesReceived: false,
    featuredCompaniesReceived: false,
    companies: undefined,
    featuredCompanies: undefined,
};

export function companies(state: CompanyState = companyState, action: CompaniesActionType): CompanyState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.COMPANIES_RECEIVED:
            return { ...state, companiesReceived: true, companies: action.companies };
        case ActionTypes.FEATURED_COMPANIES_RECEIVED:
            return { ...state, featuredCompaniesReceived: true, featuredCompanies: action.companies };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function company(state: CompanyState = companyState, action: CompanyActionType): CompanyState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.COMPANY_RECEIVED:
            return { ...state, companyReceived: true, company: action.company };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Now I have a component consuming that state and because I defined those props as optional in my reducer, so too I had to with HomePage as they will be passed as props to HomePage:

**HomePage.tsx**

```
export default class HomePage extends Component<{
    featuredCompanies?: Array<Company>,
    companies?: Array<Company>,
    countries?: Array<Country>,
    className: string
}, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Main>
```

And in HomePage, the tree continues as it renders CompanyList:

```
<CompanyList
className="ft-company-list"
companies={this.props.companies}
countries={this.props.countries} />
```

so CompanyList will also have to define companies and countries as optional params to it's React Component definition and so on and so on for any other sub components that these two props trickle down to...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think the `?` in typescript stands for optional, not nullable. This means, that you coould do this `companies: null` , and you won't need the `?`, except if you plan to create an object `CompanyState` that contains all the props except `companies`.

Comment: No you can't.  If I remove ? from CompanyState and try to set company:  null or to undefined it complains that it needs a valid Company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, if you ensure it a non-null type, then you can use the `!` postfix after the identifer. In you code, it would be:

```js
<CompanyList
className="ft-company-list"
companies={this.props.companies!}
countries={this.props.countries!} />
```

see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions

Comment: there are cases where it could be null though, depending on what the API returns back to my action creators so what do you mean by `ensure it a non-null type`.  I think you're saying I'd have to handle the check for null early and ensure I don't send a null down further in my component tree if I use !

Comment: it's funny then you get a forbidden non-null assertion from eslint if you do the !

Comment: You shouldn't need to use ! all the way down. Just make it nullable if it could be null. If you're certain it's not null use !, if you're uncertain, just leave it as you have it - your setup is correct then

Comment: you can ignore this esLint rule here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320613/how-to-disable-typescript-eslint-no-non-null-assertion-rule

Comment: there is another way to resolve it, you can use `||` or `??` to set up a default value if it returns a null value.

Comment: I ended up just making the sub component props with `| undefined` in them.  For example: `function companyList(companies: Array<Company> | undefined, countries: Array<Country> | undefined) {`

Comment: Ya but Tim lower components will complain if you don't give it a `| undefined` for props coming in from redux state where those props defined in reducers are are nullable so...that means the majority of components will need to specify a `| undefined` as part of the prop definitions in those react components

Comment: to may specifying ! means you are sure they will never be null but I don't think anyone can guarantee anything so I feel like using `!` is a hack and not trustworthy.  What happens if you put `!` and you were wrong, and there is an edge case where undefined was passed!