# Function should return type of a not-null parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts `x` and `y`. One of the coordinates is always `null`. Another one is always `number`. The function returns the value of a not-null coordinate: either `x` or `y`. The function always returns a number.

```
function test({ x, y }: { x: null; y: number } | { x: number; y: null }): number {
  if (x === null) {
    // y should be recognized as 'number', but it is 'number | null'
    return y; // ERROR
  }
  return x;
}


test({x: null, y: 42 }); // 42
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgN6IB4A0iAnogL4BciueVYIANgwNwl0gC2ARigE7mIAPtXztufVsXZNyASjE9%202AFCJEMYIkx5EAXn2J6TWdVVrEAegslEaABZxGAE0Q9EvFBDgBzMDABeKC4AhmiIAOT04rzhRFwgUOqJMGGRnIpChowM4WZqHlAgvEjErFaIAKIASlUA8lVmZGYFRUh4zMpNysqoGDi0WUxEUogALABMcsxAA)

Is it possible to keep the return type of this function always as a `number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, TypeScript infers `number | null` for both `x` and `y` as it won't take into account any dependencies between them that follow from the union type. You simplify the problem a bit by not destructuring the argument object, which will allow TypeScript to identify it as a [discriminating union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) and narrow its type based on checks on `x` (or `y`):

```
function test(arg: { x: null; y: number } | { x: number; y: null }): number {
  if (arg.x === null) {
    return arg.y;
  }
  return arg.x;
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgIYCcDmAXIgN6IAexYIANjQNyICeVIAtgEYq6IC+iAH1IVWnboxaJqdPgEpRXHiQBQyxIhjBEOAgDpyiALzGptGrNJr1iXCighcSPPl1N6V3ldv3HiZ-vdPVVQMTBJKUzoAGmZiABYAJjl6IA)

Comment: It works, thanks! You have my upvote! I wonder why destructuring plays a role here tho.

Comment: It's because `arg` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), which is one of the only places in TS where checking the type of one value (the discriminant property) has an implication on other values (the parent object and its other properties).  If you destructure into two variables, `x`, and `y`, the types are seen as separate *uncorrelated* union types and checking one has no implication for the other. I've filed [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about your requirements you can try the following:

```
function test({ x, y }: { x: null; y: number } | { x: number; y: null }): number {
  return x === null && y !== null ? y : x!;
}
```

`!` is the so called [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

> A new `!` post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its
> operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type
> checker is unable to conclude that fact.

Comment: It works, thanks! You have my upvote! My eslint has a problem with it tho: `Forbidden non-null assertion.(@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion)`. Thankfully, it's a warning, not an error.

Comment: You are welcome. ESLint is sometimes a bit annoying. If you want to disable the warning see [How to disable @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60320613/2436655) :)